# How do I make a text file in its own class

Tags: java, class, textfield

My code below shows how to make a textfile in main. However, when I put this in its own class it does not work. How can I take this code out of my main and put it in a separate class?

```
try {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
    pw.println("this is my file content");
    pw.close();
    System.out.println("hi");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RST.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

This works but it is all in main. I want to take it out and put it in its own class.

Comment: It's not clear what you want, what's your problem and/or what you already tried to solve it.
I should say move the code to some classes and call that classes.

Comment: I made it more clear hope it helps

Comment: In fact it is very clear that the guy requires an example on how to encapsulate its code into a class. No need for additional explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not explained what features you want for the class, but this should be a good start:

```
public class MySuperDuperTextClass {
   private File file = null;
   private String content = null;
   public File getFile() { return file; }
   public void setFile( File file ) { this.file = file; }
   public String getContent() { return content; }
   public void setContent( String content ) { this.content = content; }

public MySuperDuperTextClass( String filename ){
  try {
    File file = new File ( filename );
    if (!file.exists()){ 
        file.createNewFile(); 
    }
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
      pw.println("this is my file content");
      pw.close();
      System.out.println("hi");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RST.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   // somewhere you may want to store the content of the file into
   // the this.content file:
   this.content = new 
       String(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename))); 
}
```

I'm coding the answer directly, so you should deal with any compiler errors.